# jar file can't find org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display

Tags: java, command-line, jar

I have an app in a .jar file that throws this error when I run from the command line:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display
```

I searched the problem and all the solutions I find are relative to an IDE. In this case there is no IDE for me to configure.

I'm not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A space in the path name name is the culprit. I moved the entire folder elsewhere and the problem went away. 
[image: Note the funky rendering of the folder name]